# How to get just folder path without the actual folder name?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am wondering how I can get the file path, 1 level above the folder passed into a string.

So I have the following code:

```
 foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in rootDir.GetDirectories())
  {
     string test = directory.FullName;
  }
```

This returns the directory name including the folder name so it is returning this:

c:\test\FolderName

Where FolderName is the name  of the directory object.

How would I get only c:\test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`directory.Parent` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.parent.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`string test = Path.GetDirectoryName(directory.FullName);`